# Push to a queue passed as a function parameter

Tags: c++, function, parameters, queue, push

I'm trying to `push` to a `queue` inside of a function called in multiple places.

From my limited experience, if I pass the `queue` as is, I think it will be a copy, so only the copy will be `push`ed.

How can the original `queue` be passed as a function parameter and `push`ed inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it by reference. Something like void myFunc(queue& q). This will pass the address of the queue so it is efficient. It is better than passing a pointer to the queue because myFunc() does not have to worry about it being a null pointer.

Comment: OK, Let me know if you get stuck.